# How can I use __init__() in python django

Tags: python, django, uuid

Good day, I have the following problem that I'm trying to resolve. What I need to achieve is having the patient id generated as i run the app and print it. But it is not doing what  I want. I want each time that I will run the app, and calling the view, a new id as to get generated and printed for now. 
Here's a class that I have created to generate the id:

```
import uuid

class PatientId:
    def __init__(self, id_number):
        self.id_number = id_number

    @staticmethod
    def generate_patient_id_number():
        prefix = 'HSCM'
        generated_id = str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper())
    return  '%s-%s' % (prefix, generated_id)
```

and in my views.py,

```
    from utilities.id_number import PatientId

# Create your views here.
def show_id(request, self):
    id = PatientId(self).generate_patient_id_number()
    print(id)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Will appreciate any help

Comment: `PatientId(self)` creates a new `PatientId` object with `self` as the value for `id_number`. Is that desired? Also, what is `self`? If it’s the object instance, it needs to be the first argument, and if it isn’t you should give it a different name.

Comment: What is `self` in `show_id(request, self)`? Why are you passing it to a view function?

Comment: @poke I tried to pass self because the traceback is giving me this error: show_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @JamesFenwick I tried to pass self because the traceback is giving me this error: show_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Please post the entire traceback

Comment: The `show_id()` error seems to be a separate problem of its own (i.e there's a problem with how you define/call the view, if it was a class-based-view it would have been `show_id(self, request)` not `show_id(request, self)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have `PatientId` as a class, but with that given class you can use it like this, since `generate_patient_id_number()` is a static method

```
id = PatientId.generate_patient_id_number()
# id is e.g. 'HSCM-E9E10C'
```

### You don't need a class for this

In Python you don't need to make everything into a class, so if you had a module called `id_number` you can simply put that function there (and then you can use it from anywhere, a view, a class, a Django model, etc)

```
# id_number.py

 def generate_patient_id_number():
        prefix = 'HSCM'
        generated_id = str(uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper())
        return  '%s-%s' % (prefix, generated_id)
```

and use it like this

```
from utilities import id_number

def show_id(request):
    id = id_number.generate_patient_id_number()
    print(id)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Comment: I tried it, but having this error: generate_patient_id_number() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: If it is indeed a static method like the code in the question, then you can call it directly with `id = PatientId.generate_patient_id_number()`, but to simply generate the UUIDs, a function is sufficient (which you can call from a class or a Django model e.g.)

Comment: even this latest one still giving the same eroor

Comment: If it's a `@staticmethod`, `id = PatientId.generate_patient_id_number()` is how you would call it. If it's not static, you need to instantiate the class first e.g. `p = PatientId(); p.generate_patient_id_number()`. But you don't even need a class for what you want to achieve, a simple function will do.